# Why does this collection seem to contain objects?

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, app-config

I have a class "ImageElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection" containing elements of a class "ImageElement : ConfigurationElement".

Using the advice of some other very intelligent persons here on StackOverflow, I have figured out how to make use of these items in my program:

```
MonitorConfig Config = (MonitorConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MonitorConfig");
```

However, when I attempt to access the items in this collection...

```
foreach (var image in Config.Images) Debug.WriteLine(image.Name);
```

...I end up with squiggly lines under the Name property because "image" has been declared as an object rather than as an ImageElement in spite of my best efforts.

Is this something I'm doing wrong in my declarations, or is this just something everyone just deals with by exchanging "var" for "ImageElement" in that foreach up there?

Code for configuration handler found below:

```
public class MonitorConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Frequency", DefaultValue = 5D, IsRequired = false)]
    public double Frequency
    {
        get { return (double)this["Frequency"]; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Images", IsRequired = false)]
    public ImageElementCollection Images
    {
        get { return (ImageElementCollection)this["Images"]; }
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ImageElement), AddItemName = "Image")]
public class ImageElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public ImageElement this[object elementKey]
    {
        get { return (ImageElement)BaseGet(elementKey); }
    }

    public void Add(ImageElement element)
    {
        base.BaseAdd(element);
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new ImageElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((ImageElement)element).Name;
    }
}

public class ImageElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Name", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return (string)this["Name"]; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try switching out `var image` for `ImageElement image`. It may be ambiguous and just treating it as type object. (edit: in your foreach, if I wasn't clear...)

edit2: I see you've already done that and seem to imply it works. Then I guess I mean to say "yes, that's how I get around it."

Comment: Yes, that works fine. It just seems strange to me that something which is *definitely* of type X (like, when you hover over it, the tooltip says "ImageElement") doesn't get typed as such when declared with "var." Thought maybe that meant my handler was broken?

Comment: ConfigurationElementCollection implements ICollection and IEnumerable, which provide the compiler with no hint as to the type of elements it contains so it defaults to elements of type Object. If the collection implemented the generic interface IEnumerable<T> the compiler would be able to determine that it should use T in place of var.

Comment: Can I implement IEnumerable<T> myself? (Ok, yes, I'm just going to go try that and see, but still...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew Kennan provided the answer in the comments above: this collection seems to contain only objects because it doesn't implement IEnumerable<T>.

Furthermore, it is possible to fix that problem by slightly adjusting the Configuration Handler. Simply add the IEnumerable interface as follows...

```
public class ImageElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection, IEnumerable<ImageElement>
```

...And then stick a method somewhat like this in the body of the class:

```
public new IEnumerator<ImageElement> GetEnumerator()
{
    var iter = base.GetEnumerator();
    while (iter.MoveNext()) yield return (ImageElement)iter.Current;
}
```

Thank you, Andrew.

Comment: (Btw, if you would like to, like... answer, I'll pick yours. :P)